# Fill array to nearest multiple of 10 without going over

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Been building an encryption program. I plan to have the characters mixed around (for example: 1234567890 would be encrypted as 6345809127).

Unfortunately to mix in a specific pattern I would need a string to be a multiple of ten, so my plan is to add a character like `'` until the string had a length of a multiple of ten. For example, if I input hello (5 characters) the script would insert `'` until it's 10 characters, so it would look like `hello'''''`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: First rule of security, never create your own crypto.

Comment: `have been building an encryption program` ALARM BELLS. Just...don't.

Comment: First rule of security is don't roll your crypto program out to a public interface, _creating_ your own can help you understand how they work and the process between A to Z. No need to immediately assume security is paramount to the system. Not everyone is building an A* web service!

Comment: @jcubic  don't worry, it's just for little things at school, like encrypting messages and then texting them so other people can't read them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the obvious problems of rolling your own encryption (about a million, billion times too long for an answer here) what you're asking is quite simple.

```js
var padStr = "''''''''''";
var input = "hello";

var output = input + padStr.substring(10-input.length);
console.log(output);
console.log(output.length);
```

That covers `input` string *up to 10*, but not *multiples of 10*. Thats only slightly more complex though:

```js
var padStr = "''''''''''";
var input = "helloworldlongerthan10";

var output = input + padStr.substring(input.length%10);
console.log(output);
console.log(output.length);
```

Comment: Won't work with multiples of 10, creating a negative substring value. Fix: .substring(10-input.length%10)

Comment: @yezzz - that wont work either. I was updating as you commented with a working solution.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. +1

Comment: @jamiec you're correct... the deduction logic was flawed... simple modulo works great